# Texture not showing on unwrapped mesh with Texture Coordinate node in Cycles

Tags: texturing, uv

I looked everywhere and found nothing related to this issue. I must have done something wrong because every time I've done this it worked except this time. I unwrapped my mesh with Marks, added a texture, the UV test Grid. I went into Texture View and nothing. I then added the Texture Coordinate node, and still no texture. WHat am I doing wrong this time?

**The texture does, however, appear in the render/render view.**

[image]

Comment: Is your material actually assigned to any faces? Iss your texture using the displayed UV layer?

Comment: Yes, I assigned the faces. It should be for the second question. Not sure how to check.

Comment: Check the Object Data tab of the properties window and see if you have more than one UV Map, otherwise share a Blendfile